# Search Excel with multiple string criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to search a description cell for ANY words (criteria) from a predefined list, and pull the relevant dollar amount for the item from the adjacent cell.

To illustrate, here is my setup:

```
   A   |   B   |   C   |     D    |    E    |   F    |

 Date  | Descr.| Amount|   Cat1   |   Cat2  |  Cat3  |
```

D,E,F: Each one of these are item categories.  If the item in that row belongs to a category, I would like its amount to populate that category cell in that same row.  Each category cell has a formula to test for this and perform the operation.

My first thought was to use VLookup, but I have a list of lookup values.  I haven't been able to successfully do that.  Each of the category cells has a formula like this -->

`=IF(SUM(COUNTIF($B10,{"*costco*","*saputo*","*t & t*"}))>0,$C10," ")`

Column B refers to the description, which is searched for any of the criteria.  If any of the words are contained in the description, the cell is filled with the amount from column C, otherwise its left with a space.

This works perfectly as is, however I need the criteria (costco, saputo, t&t in this case) to be flexible (add or remove strings to the list) rather than hard-coded in the formula.  This is my issue: the formula stops working if I replace the criteria with a reference to another cell.  I'm relatively new to excel and not familiar with restrictions/constraints of its functions, which I suspect is the issue.

Any help is much appreciated, let me know if I need to provide more info.

Ankit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Name (like a named range, but refers to a value rather than a range.)

For Excel 2007 and 2010, on the Formulas tab, Defined Names group, Name Manager
For Excel 2003 Insert, Names, Define

Create a new Name (lets use the name "KeyWords") , set it "Refers To" value to

```
={"*costco*","*saputo*","*t & t*"}
```

Formula then becomes  **EDIT** enter as an array formula

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIF($B10,KeyWords))>0,$C10," ")
```

Editing the list then becomes editing the value of KeyWords refers to value.  This can be done through the Name Manager, or if you wish, through VBA

**EDIT**

Sample VBA

```
Sub SetKeyWords()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim nm As Name

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set nm = wb.Names("KeyWords")
    nm.RefersTo = "={""NewString""}"

End Sub
```

Comment: Chris, your solution would be an ideal setup for me, but excel is only recognizing the first term in the referred value ("*costco*") when KeyWords is used in the formula.  Any ideas?

Comment: Enter the formula as an array formula (press ctrl-shift-enter instead of just enter)

Comment: Great that solved it!  One last question, how would I go about editing the value of the "refer to value" using VBA?

Comment: @Ankit added sample of VBA.  By the way, if you find the answer useful please accept it

Comment: Chris, would I still be entering the refer to value items manually?  My goal is to be able to have a column of keywords that VBA can populate the refer to value with.  However, it doesnt seem like that's possible with this setup?

Comment: @Ankit it would be relatively easy to build the refer to value string from a range.  Just loop through the cells to construct the string and assign it to the refers to value at the end.  Could be called by the user on demand, or maybe on a change event triggered when the range is edited

Comment: @Chris I've sorted it out, thanks for your help Chris!  I wasn't using proper syntax for some of my code.

Answer (score 1):

Load the strings you are seeking into an array (via converting a range into an array, or having the user select the strings from a small form you design)

```
 Sub MyLookup(arrCategories() As Variant)
    Dim searchrange As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim count As Integer
    'set searchrange to the proper column
    For Each xCell In searchrange
       For Each catg In arrCategories
          If xCell = catg Then
              'Do something here
          End If
       Next catg
    Next xCell       
 End Sub
```

You may need to adjust your string array based on whether case matters.  Depending on the size of your set of data, it might be better to convert `searchrange` into an array.

There may be a faster way to see if certain strings are found within a given range, but this is the general idea.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around the logic.  Is arrCategories or catg the array that holds the strings to be searched?

Comment: @Ankit arrCategories is an array holding the strings `"*costco*","*saputo*","*t & t*"`.  `catg` represents the current item in `arrCategories` as the loop progresses (so equal to "*costco*" during the first iteration of the loop).

Comment: Ah, now I understand the logic, thank you.  However, the line "If xcel = catg" does an exact match, I need an approximate match (the description column is a sentence).  I've tried to use the Like operator but haven't had any success.  Perhaps there's a way to use wildcards in this situation, I couldn't figure out how?

Comment: Using [RegEx](http://www.tmehta.com/regexp/) may do the trick.  If it's just one word out of the sentence, you can use `InStr()` to look for it.

Comment: InStr worked thanks, good to know about RegEx for future.  Thanks for your help, Chris' was more applicable in my setup but this has been very helpful, I'm sure it'll come in handy for future projects.